# svg filter shadow path repair

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

How do I fix the gap between shadows? I would like the shadow to be continuous, not intermittent. Shadow should be in one black line without any spaces

This is my example:

```css
.wave-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.wave-container .wave {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background-size: 160px 50px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='60' height='10' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 60 10' version='1.1'><defs><filter id='shadow' x='-10' y='-10' width='15' height='15'><feOffset result='offOut' in='SourceAlpha' dx='0' dy='-1'></feOffset><feGaussianBlur result='blurOut' in='offOut' stdDeviation='1'></feGaussianBlur><feBlend in='SourceGraphic' in2='blurOut' mode='normal'></feBlend>  </filter></defs><path d='M0,5 C25,0 35,10 60,5 v5 H0' filter='url(%23shadow)'/></svg>");
    height: 50px;
    left: -160px;
    
}
.wave-container .wave.w1 {
    bottom: 0;
}
.wave-container .wave.w2 {
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wave-container">
        <div class="wave w1"></div>
        <div class="wave w2"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You make it longer by how much your shadow radius is and you trim it. Pretty much like you would do in ***any*** visual editor. Also note your element ***needs*** to have a width expressed in round pixels. Otherwise you'll see either whiter or darker lines where you join the two pieces, due to pixel anti-aliasing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think, what should be modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discontinuity you are seeing is the fading of the shadow as it reaches the edge of the shape.

Instead of ending your path exactly at the edge of the SVG, try extending the shape a bit further off the left and right edges.  In the example below I have extend the shape wider on each side with a five unit line segment.

```css
.wave-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.wave-container .wave {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background-size: 160px 50px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='60' height='10' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 60 10' version='1.1'><defs><filter id='shadow' x='-10' y='-10' width='15' height='15'><feOffset result='offOut' in='SourceAlpha' dx='0' dy='-1'></feOffset><feGaussianBlur result='blurOut' in='offOut' stdDeviation='1'></feGaussianBlur><feBlend in='SourceGraphic' in2='blurOut' mode='normal'></feBlend>  </filter></defs><path d='M-5,5 L0,5 C25,0 35,10 60,5 H 65 v5 H-5' filter='url(%23shadow)'/></svg>");
    height: 50px;
    left: -160px;
    
}
.wave-container .wave.w1 {
    bottom: 0;
}
.wave-container .wave.w2 {
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wave-container">
        <div class="wave w1"></div>
        <div class="wave w2"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An idea is to keep the SVG simple and apply `drop-shadow` filter

```css
.wave-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.wave-container .wave {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-size: 160px 50px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='60' height='10' viewbox='0 0 60 10' version='1.1'><path fill='white' d='M0,5 C25,0 35,10 60,5 v5 H0' /></svg>");
  height: 50px;
  left: -160px;
  filter:drop-shadow(0 -4px 3px #000);
}

.wave-container .wave.w1 {
  bottom: 0;
}

.wave-container .wave.w2 {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wave-container">
  <div class="wave w1"></div>
  <div class="wave w2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: drop-shadow is not supported for IE, but i would like to see there? I'm encoding svg and then it's also works on IE

Comment: @JanuszO this an alternave as actually I don't see how I can correct the SVG but wait and you will probably get the SVG solution